# Terminal Python 2.3/3.7

Tags: python, terminal

So coding with python on mac is much more complicated than I thought, because OS X uses Python 2.7 I can't delete it. However, when I run code in Visual Studio Code it would open terminal and run Python 2.7 syntax. Which is really inconvenient seen as 2.7 is disbanding soon.

So I am pretty much asking if I can change the terminal workforce to use 2.7 instead of 3.7. Or I have seen people use 'Output' instead of terminal.

Comment: Also i set Visual Studio Code to Python 3 but when i run it in terminal, terminal thinks its python 2

Comment: You can install Python3 using `brew install python3` (assuming you're using Homebrew; if not, why not?!? :P ). Then either run it explicitly with `python3`, `pip3` etc, or make a virtual environment (using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)).

Comment: I dont think i explained it very well. What im trying to say is that I already have Python 3 but i have Python 2 (which is preinstalled because Macs need it) But i'm trying to learn python 3 which i cant do because it keeps to python 2

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments explains what to fo with vscode; my previous comment explains what to do with terminal (except you don’t have to brew p3 if you already have it).